# Is there a way to include WP Posts in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

I have a client who wants to publish newsletter directly calling the content from WordPress (image, title, content) without copy/paste.
Tokens give access to all possible date inside CiviCRM but I can't find anything that would create a link to WP's content .

Other way to ask is: are WP posts exposed in CiviCRM?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I need the same function. This looks like it would meet the need, but appears abandoned:

https://github.com/skyslasher/wp-civi-mosaico

Comment: good to know. I'll ask on mattermost about this extension

Comment: Love to know what you find out!

Comment: this is what I got: `Note that that plugin got split into three plugin/extensions, though it still needs an update to work with Mosaico 3.x and the current Civi.`
:-/

Comment: I updated my answer to point to the newer, post split extension.   It seems we’re at the mercy of someone with deeper pockets and/or development skills to take this starting point and run with it.

Comment: it seems also not possible to use shortcodes. We installed the 'Newsletter' extension in WP for a client and it integrates smoothly posts and pages in a message template. This would be a very cool feature within Mosaico